# How to change octaves on Yamaha E363

Tags: piano, transposition, octave

I have read the [documentation](https://files.bbystatic.com/zgJX7fI99UFCegA9VZPOwQ%3D%3D/62D40679-2826-4293-991F-CE5AB018B6CE.pdf) but it doesn't explain how to transpose or change the octave setting or else it is not implementing my changes. Function > Transpose > Adjust -/+ keys but they LED display doesn't change when I hit the lowest keys on the bass cleff of the keyboard. They still say 8va.

Answer (score 2):

> doesn't change when I hit the lowest keys on the bass cleff of the
> keyboard.?

You need to use the + and - buttons which are under the numpad. Note that you can only transpose +/- 12 semi-tones with this function.

In page 46 of your manual there is also a `octave` parameter, which I guess you will need to adjust using the + and - buttons and not the white and black keys.

Answer (score 0):

To transpose by octave, press the `FUNCTION` button until the `M.OCTAVE` (Main voice), `D.OCTAVE` (Dual voice), or `S.OCTAVE` (Split voice) indicator appears on the display, then use the `+/-` buttons to adjust. The possible range is -2/+2 octaves.

See page 46 in the manual linked in th OP.